# Upgrading MiniConda from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

I accidentally installed the wrong Windows version (32-bit) of MiniConda onto my work computer and want to change it to 64-bit.  What would be the best way to accomplish this task without causing issues of dependencies?

Would it be to just download the 64-bit installer [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and hopefully it can correct the dependencies? Or should I uninstall all of the files in the /miniconda/ folder and then install with the correct .exe file?

Any advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upgrade from 32 to 64 bit

1. save your environment configuration in a file:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

2. uninstall miniconda 32-bit
3. install miniconda 64-bit
4. restore your environment

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

And when using Miniconda familiarize yourself with:

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#